# pointerInput on many elements not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, button, input, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a custom button that makes animations when you start clicking and when you release the click. This works, but I have a LazyVerticalGrid with several buttons and this animation only works on some.

```
.pointerInput(isPressed) {
  awaitPointerEventScope {
    isPressed = if (isPressed) {
      waitForUpOrCancellation()
      false
   } else {
      awaitFirstDown(false)
      haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
      true
    }
  }
}
```